# Bind DNS serverdo not answer domain name

Tags: dns, bind, webmin

I setup my bind server but I can't access my web server using my domain name. does anybody knows What can be wrong?
My server can connect by IP but can not connect by domain name.
I tried to turn off firewall but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the server by name from the server or a different box? If a different machine, is that machine setup to use the bind server as the DNS server? If not you have to configure the DHCP server to set the BIND server as the DNS server. You can also use nslookup to query the bind server. This is of course assuming you are using NIX

Comment: Thats the result whe I use nslookup
:~$ nslookup tumercado.com 192.168.0.100
Server:         192.168.0.100
Address:        192.168.0.100#53

Name:   tumercado.com
Address: 99.242.78.103

juliano@WebServer:~$ nslookup tumercado.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: It looks as if you do not have BIND configured properly. The address was resolved to an external address. There is a tutorial on how to setup BIND here. You will need to configure your resolve.conf, named.conf, possibly your dhcpd.conf. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04